# How to limit the number of records in the Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**Hello everyone, how to limit the number of results using a serializer?**

In short, there is a table of comments, which can contain different types of posts.

```
class CourseComment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    content = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and here related table

```
class CourseMessage(models.Model):
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    text = models.TextField()   # RAW Format must exclude specials chars before publish
    is_pinned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comments = GenericRelation('CourseComment')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I made the serializer according to the documentation
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

```
class CourseMessages(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = Author(source='authorid', read_only=True)
    files = MessageFiles(source='coursemessageattachedfile_set', many=True)      
    message_comments = MessageComments(source='comments', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CourseMessage
        fields = ['text', 'updated_at', 'user', 'files', 'message_comments']


class MessageComments(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(value)
        serializer = Comments(value, read_only=True, source='last_comments')
        return serializer.data


class Comments(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = Author(source='user', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CourseComment
        fields = ['content', 'author']
```

Everything works well, but I would like to see first 3 comments.
Maybe someone has encountered such a problem, or can advise how to do it better.
I get this data for the RetrieveAPIView detail page. The first three comments are required for display on the front.

**requirements**
*Django==3.2.5
djangorestframework==3.12.4*

**Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 3):

I think you gain nothing by instructing the serializer to return a subset of a resultset. I think the best way is to filter the subset when making the query, or filtering the array after serializing:

```
result_set = CourseComment.objects.all()[:3] # model
three_first = Comment(result_set, many=True).data # serializer
```

or

```
result_set = CourseComment.objects.all() # model
three_first = Comment(result_set, many=True).data[:3] # serializer
```

Or you can even send a subset of the resultset to the serializer:

```
result_set = CourseComment.objects.all() # model
three_first = Comment(result_set[:3], many=True).data # serializer
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [SerializerMethodField()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

So your code should look like this:

```
class CourseMessages(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = Author(source='authorid', read_only=True)
    files = MessageFiles(source='coursemessageattachedfile_set', many=True)      
    message_comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_message_comments(self, obj):
        message_comments = Comments.objects.all()[:3]
        return MessageComments(message_comments, source='comments', many=True, read_only=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = CourseMessage
        fields = ['text', 'updated_at', 'user', 'files', 'message_comments']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a queryset as:

```
class ViewName(generics.RetriveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = Comments
    queryset = CourseComment.objects.all()
```

then you can use inside your list function:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = Comments(self.get_queryset().order_by('-id')[:3], many = True)
```

Hope it will work for you.